# copy constructor problem with const attribute

Tags: c++

```
class exemple{
const int a

exemple(exemplec const &item){
}

};
```

I need to make a copy constructor for a project with a const attribute, I don't have a cloue how to make it.

Comment: const int a;
  public:    
    exemple(exemple const &item) : a(item.a) {}
try

Answer (score 2):

Do as below, make the copy-constructor public, fix a typo, copy the member's value.

```
class exemple
{
    const int a;
  public:    
    exemple(exemple const &item) : a(item.a) {}
};
```

You can initialize constant member using initializer list like the code.